# No scrollbar in firefox while overflow:auto set to body

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am having problem to get scrollbar if the browser resized to very small. In browsers apart from Firefox a scrollbar appears if it is resized vary small.

The code is shown in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tapas_23571113/aEH3h/) and you can find it in fullscreen mode [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tapas_23571113/aEH3h/embedded/result/). If you open the fullscreen mode in firefox and resize it to width less than 546px, you will see there is no scrollbar, but it is in chorme or ie.

Comment: I think the body element is already overflow auto. Why are you using absolute positioning for the form? Use relative and it will display scrollbars.

Comment: @AramKocharyan As you can see in the fullscreen mode the div is centered both horizontally and vertically and I need this so I did it by absolute positioning. Is there any way to align div in this a way without absolute positioning?

Comment: margin: 0 auto; for horizontal centred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its Firefox's default behavior. Check screenshot.

[image]